# How to add all catalog using GIT without .pyc file?

Tags: python, git

How to add all catalog using GIT witout .pyc file?

```
git add catalog_name
git commit -m "Update"
git push
```

What add and where?

Comment: And by `catalog` do you mean a directory instead?

Answer (score 3):

use .gitignore file. add '*.pyc' to it.
The file is located in root directory of your repo i.e. where you did `git init`

Here is a good .gitignore file for python projects, containing common extension to ignore in git commit.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore